# "Incomplete implementation" warning in XCode 4.0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

This application is rewritten code from the [Cococa and Objective C Up and Running](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596804792) book.

As I try to understand everything in the beginning, I would like to know, where I made a mistake, in the code below. To me, everything looks fine.

Could you, therefore, help me identify the source of the warning:

```
Incomplete Implementation
```

I got this in the `@implementation Photo` line in `Photo.m` source code file?

*Photo.h*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Photo : NSObject{

    NSString* caption;
    NSString* photographer;    
}

+ (Photo*) photo;

- (NSString*) caption;
- (NSString*) photographer;

- (void) setCaption: (NSString*)input;
- (void) setPhotographer: (NSString*)input;

@end
```

*Photo.m*

```
#import "Photo.h"


@implementation Photo  // <- Incomplete Implementation?

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setCaption:@"Default Caption"];
        [self setPhotographer:@"Default Photographer"];
    }

    return self;
}


+ (Photo*) caption {
    Photo* newPhoto = [[Photo alloc] init];
    return [newPhoto autorelease];
}


- (NSString*) caption {
    return caption;
}


- (NSString*) photographer {
    return photographer;
}


- (void) setCaption:(NSString *)input {
    [caption autorelease];
    caption = [input retain];
}


- (void) setPhotographer: (NSString *)input {
    [photographer autorelease];
    photographer = [input retain];
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [self setCaption:nil];
    [self setPhotographer:nil];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

*I use Snow Leopard 10.6.7 and Xcode 4.0.0.*

Comment: Your question got answered quickly (see below), but as an aside, is there any reason you are using properties and @synthesize for your variables instead of manually doing the getter and setter?

Comment: @Jesse: Hi, Jesse. Yes, you are correct, my question got answerred instantly. There is no reason at all. I just started learning *Objective-C*. If you have anything to add to make my code better, I will be happy to absorb it. As my knowledge about Objective-C is very limited, I have to follow, what the book offers.

Comment: ill put it in my answer real quick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless its a typo, your Class method defined as `+ (Photo*) Photo`; is not implemented (there is a + `(Photo*) Caption {}` method which looks its just an accident.

Edit: A simpler way to do have this functionality is to use *properties*, which are a shortcut that create the getter and setter for a variable for us, (see this link for a good beginner's tutorial: [iPhone 101](http://www.idev101.com/learn/properties.html)) for your instance variables like so:

in your .h file:

```
@interface Photo : NSObject{

    NSString* caption;
    NSString* photographer;    
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *caption;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *photographer;
@end
```

in your .m file:

```
@implementation Photo
@synthesize caption, photographer;

    //Other stuff (init and any custom methods for class etc.. NOT getters and setters for variables)
    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [caption release];
        [photographer release];

        [super dealloc];
    }
```

Comment: +1, hi Jesse. Yes, that was my mistake. Thank you very much for your answer. You are very kind.

Comment: thank you for this additional value. Because, you were caring and provided me with additional practical advices, which will help me with writing better Objective-C code, I have reevaluated my selection of the best answer. I think, this is the best answer now, and therefore, I am marking this as the _Accepted Answer_.

Comment: as I see, it is expected, that virtually every Objective-C property has its own setter and getter, and that their member variables are never set directly.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori: In fact, other objects _cannot_ access member variables directly, by default. This is governed by the [scope of the ivars](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF127).

Answer (score 4):

You are receiving this error because in your header file you declared that there would be a method:

```
+ (Photo*) photo;
```

but you didn't implement it in the m file.

EDIT:

It looks like this:

```
+ (Photo*) caption {
    Photo* newPhoto = [[Photo alloc] init];
    return [newPhoto autorelease];
}
```

should be:

```
+ (Photo*) photo {
    Photo* newPhoto = [[Photo alloc] init];
    return [newPhoto autorelease];
}
```

Comment: +1 and thank you as well. I have overlooked that, as many things are new to me. I switched from Visual Studio and Visual C++, and this is my second day on XCode. You helped.

Answer (score 4):

In general, when you mouse over the warning, it will not tell you which method it is missing, but there are at least two other ways to get this information:

1. Type Cmd-4 or select the Issue Navigator view (the ! in a triangle icon), then expand the "Semantic Issue" warning for this issue.  You will then see a message to the effect of "Method definition for "" not found.
2. Type Cmd-7 or select the Log View (the rightmost icon that looks like a caption bubble), then select the appropriate issue from the list.  You will see the same message.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `+photo` because you accidentally typed `caption`:

```
+ (Photo*) caption {
    Photo* newPhoto = [[Photo alloc] init];
    return [newPhoto autorelease];
}
```

should be

```
+ (Photo*) photo {
    Photo* newPhoto = [[Photo alloc] init];
    return [newPhoto autorelease];
}
```

Comment: +1, hi Jeremy, and thank you very much. you really helped me, and your answer was virtually instant. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your .m file does not have the implementation for:

```
+ (Photo*) photo;
```

That's the missing method.

Comment: +1, hi Mihir. I was overlooking that line. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
+ (Photo*) caption {
    Photo* newPhoto = [[Photo alloc] init];
    return [newPhoto autorelease];
 }
```

to

```
+ (Photo*) photo {
    Photo* newPhoto = [[Photo alloc] init];
    return [newPhoto autorelease];
}
```